# $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$. What does it mean?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, notation

$f\in C(\mathbb{R})$. What does it mean?

My guess is "Differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$" but I'm not sure..

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should mean that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.  This is also often written as $C^0(\mathbb R)$ where $C^n(\mathbb R)$ means that the functions in this set are $n$ times continuously differentiable.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually make sense (I guess C is for continuous)

Comment: But it's usually denoted as $C^n(\mathbb R)$ or $\mathcal C^n(\mathbb R)$ as well as $\mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$ without parentheses.

Comment: @FrankScience: Right, thanks, I've fixed that.  Don't know what got into me... :)